# How to change text or background color in a Windows console application

Tags: c++, text, background-color

Which C++ function changes text or background color (MS Visual studio)? For example `cout<<"This text";` how to make "This text" red color.

Comment: What text? What background? Please be more specific.

Comment: So you're dealing with a console application?

Comment: Have a look at [the console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073(VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Colour isn't a C++ thing, but a property of your **terminal**. If your terminal speaks ANSI (e.g. any Linux terminal, or DOS or Windows NT if you add `DEVICE=C:\DOS\ansi.sys` to your `config.sys`, or later Windows if you call the shell with `cmd.exe /kansicon`), then you can try the following gimmick:

```
#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW  "\x1b[33m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\x1b[36m"

#define ANSI_COLOR_BRIGHT  "\x1b[1m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\x1b[0m"


std::cout << ANSI_COLOR_RED "Hello World\n" ANSI_COLOR_RESET;
```

Wikipedia has a [list of ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes).

Comment: @Kyberias: It does in Windows NT it you [load ansi.sys](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/101875), just like in DOS, or later if you say `cmd.exe /kansicon`.

Comment: Windows 10 as of Threshold 2 supports this natively without needing arguments.

Comment: @ildjarn: Progress is unstoppable!

Answer (score 14):

You can change the colors for a console application using Win32 and here's an example on how to:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main(void) 
{ 
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
    if (hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        cout << "Error while getting input handle" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    //sets the color to intense red on blue background
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout, FOREGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);

    cout << "This is intense red text on blue background" << endl;
    //reverting back to the normal color
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Look at the MSDN documentation for the [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047.aspx) function and [Console Screen Buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes) for more information.

A more complete example on console applications using Win32 is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 nice answer... but i have to comment #include "stdafx.h" to run this code on code blocks ide.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are looking for the [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047.aspx) function. The first parameter, `hConsoleOutput`, would be the standard output handle obtained via `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)`. The second parameter is a bitwise-OR (`|`) combination of the desired [character attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088.aspx#_win32_character_attributes).

See also: [KB319883 How to change foreground colors and background colors of text in a Console window by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319883)