# C++ Set Console Text Color in Windows from Static Method

Tags: c++, windows, oop, class, console-application

Is it possible to use a static method within a class to set the text color of a console for a Windows C++ application? My code looks like this:

**Display.h:**

```
class Display {
public:
  Display();
  static void setTextColor(int color);
};
```

**Display.cpp:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "Display.h"

void Display::setTextColor(int color) {
  HANDLE cHandle;
  cHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

  SetConsoleTextAttribute(cHandle, color);
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Display.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::cout << "HI"; //Outputs default color
  Display::setTextColor(9);
  std::cout << "HI"; //Still default color

  return 0;
}
```

Can anybody please explain why this static method will not update the text color? This excat code will work if placed inline.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly for me. What do `GetStdHandle` and `SetConsoleTextAttribute` return? Btw, for anyone trying to find it, 9 is `FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY`.

Comment: @chris Gah.... I must have made an error. It's all good now.

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285825/how-to-change-text-or-background-color-in-a-windows-console-application