# ANSI color codes in Windows 7 console using ansicon

Tags: c, windows, console

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8285969/4598939), and ansicon works fine, I can output colored text from a batch file:

```
@echo ←[1m←[31mTESTANSI←[0m
```

But when I run this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
  printf("\x1b[31mTESTANSI");
  return 0;
}
```

I see no colors, but this:

```
←[31mTESTANSI
```

Edit: here is a simple winapi solution that works for me. It is based on this [article](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2ywTURfi/)

```
#ifndef __CONCOL_H__
#define __CONCOL_H__

#include <windows.h>

enum concol {
    black, dark_blue, dark_green, dark_cyan, dark_red, dark_purple, dark_yellow, dark_white,
    gray, blue, green, cyan, red, purple, yellow, white
};

inline void setcolor(enum concol textcol, enum concol backcol) {
    textcol %= 16;
    backcol %= 16;
    unsigned short wAttributes = ((unsigned) backcol << 4) | (unsigned) textcol;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), wAttributes);
}

#endif /*__CONCOL_H__*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 7 console does something weird, your program works fine on a Mac.

You must execute the program in a console you started yourself with /kansicon.

If you run the program directly from the explorer, the console may not start with ansi support enabled...  Yet another shortcoming of a dying platform.

Comment: The news of Windows death have been greatly exaggerated.

Comment: I did run the program inside a console started with /kansicon